# Binary outcome estimation from n "measurements"

Tags: estimation, binary-data, bernoulli-distribution

Assume you have a binary parameter $y$ which is either $0$ or $1$, and have $n$ measurements $\tilde{y_k}$ of it, each with a different probability $p_k$ of being correct (equal to $y$). With $k=1,..,n$.

Which would be the best (or a good) estimator of $y$ from the values of $\tilde{y_k}$ and the known values of $p_k$?

Comment: You describe $y$ as the *outcome*, so presumably it's a random variable.  One does not estimate random variables--they are random, after all!  Moreover, since you state the values of $p_k$ are *known*, it would appear there is nothing more that can possibly be learned.  What exactly are you trying to estimate, then?

Comment: Assume $y$ is $1$ (but you don't know it). Then you have 5 measurement of $y$ as $y_k={1,1,0,0,1}$. Each measurement has a probability $p_k$ (known) of being correct. Which is the best way to combine the measurement to decide if $y$ is $0$ or $1$. Would a weighed sum with weight equal to its probability and a $0.5$ threshold be the best estimate?

Comment: I see.  The language and notation are perhaps a little confusing: $y$ is not an "outcome," but rather it is a *parameter* in a model.  This parameter can have only one of two values, $0$ or $1$.  You are right that you want to estimate its value based on the measurements.  Have you considered computing the two likelihoods associated with those two values? If your measurements are independent, they are easy to compute.  You might prefer making the estimate with the larger likelihood.

Comment: I see, maximum likelihood estimator. I will try to deduct it. Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with the maximum likelihood estimator, and it is that if the likelihood is very low then I know for sure that the opposite answer is the correct. Should I look for which likelihood is farther from 0.5? I am starting to think that information theory could be useful here...

Comment: Even when the likelihood is very low you don't know anything for certain. Even so, I don't see why there's any problem with that. One likelihood will be higher than the other and that indicates which choice to make.  (With large $n$ and most $p_k$ staying away from $1$, both likelihoods are guaranteed to become extremely small: their actual values do not matter at all.)  In the absence of a loss function--which you haven't specified--the likelihood is the *only* possible tool you have for making a rational decision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40333/discussion-between-jose-ospina-and-whuber).